# Comparing two files for identical lines where the order doesn't matter

Tags: file, comparison

I have two files (which could be up to 150,000 lines long; each line is 160 bytes), which I'd like to check to see if the lines in each are the same. `diff` won't work for me (directly) because a small percentage of the lines occur in a different order in the two files. Typically, a pair of lines will be transposed.
What's the best way to see if the same lines appear in both files, but where order doesn't matter?
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's a slightly expensive way to do it (for anything larger I'd rethink this), I'd fire up python and do the following:

```
filename1 = "WHATEBVER YOUR FILENAME IS"
filename2 = "WHATEVER THE OTHER ONE IS"
file1contents = set(open(filename1).readlines())
file2contents = set(open(filename2).readlines())
if file1contents == file2contents:
    print "Yup they're the same!"
else:
    print "Nope, they differ.  In file2, not file1:\n\n"
    for diffLine in file2contents - file1contents:
        print "\t", diffLine
    print "\n\nIn file1, not file2:\n\n"
    for diffLine in file1contents - file2contents:
        print "\t", diffLine
```

That'll print the different lines if they differ.

Comment: Thanks - I'd just written something similar in Python, since there's no funky Unix voodoo magic to do it already. Problem solved!

Comment: Sort each file then run diff?

Comment: Yeah (+1), you're 100% right, I just hate using temp files! In 15 seconds in python I can have the answer and have access to the different lines in python variables...

Answer (score 1):

For only 150k lines, just hash each line and store them ordered in a lookup table. Then for each line in file two just perform the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Another python script to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

file1 = sys.argv[1]
file2 = sys.argv[2]

lines1 = open(file1,'r').readlines()
lines2 = open(file2,'r').readlines()
lines1.sort()
lines2.sort()

s = ''
for i,line in enumerate(lines1):
    if lines2[i] != line:
        print '> %s' % line
        print '< %s' % lines2[i]
        s = 'not'

print 'file %s is %s like file %s' % (file1, s, file2)
```